# if email exists go to section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need to go to x section if email exists in spreadsheet, for example i have the mail test@test.com in spreadsheet, if the mail match with the form input, instead of continue with the form registration, i want to go to end section (example page 8 instead page 2).

My code works like that:

```
//Select Items from Form
function selectedItems() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var formResponses = form.getResponses()
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1]
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses()

  var name = "";
  var email = "";
  var gender = "";

for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    switch (itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle()) {
        case "Correo electrónico:":
            email = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
            break;
        case "Sexo:":
            gender = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
            break;
        case "Nombre completo:":
            name = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};

getItems(email)
Logger.log(email)

}

//compare given email to seventh column (mail column) starting with 0... 7 in this case
function getItems(email) {
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    var spreadSheetData = spreadSheet.getDataRange()
    var rowValue = spreadSheetData.getValues()

    var columnValue = []
    for (var j in rowValue) {
       columnValue.push(rowValue[j].splice(1, 12))
    }
    console.log(columnValue)

    for (var i = 0; i < rowValue.length; i++) {
    if (rowValue[j].constructor == Array && rowValue[j].length > 0) {
        if (rowValue[i][7] == email) {
            rowValues = rowValue[i]
            console.log('verdadero')
        } else {
            console.log('falso')
        }
    }
}

    console.log(email)
    setItems(spreadSheet, rowValues)

}

// Insert items in another row
function setItems(spreadSheet, rowValues) {
   spreadSheet.appendRow(rowValues)
}
```

What i want is to prevent copy row 0, I tried with two dimensions array but i don't know how to implement... Thanks in advance

Comment: What does Excel have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry i put it like excel but was an ss... My mistake

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to use the onformsubmit of the spreadsheet.

Comment: It's simple your code makes no sense I can't figure out either.  Try using the onformsubmit approach and come back later

Comment: Could you provide a sample form and spreadsheet?

Comment: I will recreate my question.